# Powershell/PoshGit - 'Could not find ssh-agent'

Tags: git, powershell

I have installed Git version `Git-1.8.3-preview20130601.exe` from https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full+installer+official+git. I have also installed PoshGit and I am using Windows PowerShell.

When I start up PowerShell I get

*WARNING: Could not find ssh-agent*

I am able to enter `ssh-agent.exe` into the command line and the ssh agent starts up. I'm also able to do all of the Git commands, so my path to Git is probably correct.

I have been following [this guide](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/19/get-git-for-windows.aspx) to get Git working correctly in Windows.

I have already tried his suggestion of adding `$env:path += ";" + (Get-Item "Env:ProgramFiles(x86)").Value + "\Git\bin"` into my Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file and it did not work. It did not make any difference. I am looking for suggestions **other** than that solution.

---

For completeness, this is my Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file

```
# Load posh-git example profile
. 'C:\Users\________\code\posh-git\profile.example.ps1'
$env:path += ";" + (Get-Item "Env:ProgramFiles(x86)").Value + "\Git\bin"
```

Answer (score 26):

You just need to reverse those two lines in your Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 so that the PATH environment variable is updated to include the Git bin path *before* you include the posh-git profile.

On my PC this is what it looks like: I start PowerShell and get the warning message:

```
WARNING: Could not find ssh-agent
```

I locate and edit the PowerShell profile using `$profile`:

```
C:\Users\glombard> notepad $profile
```

Update the `$env:path` to include the path to git before loading the posh-git example profile:

```
$env:path += ";${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Git\bin"

# Load posh-git example profile
. 'C:\tools\poshgit\dahlbyk-posh-git-22f4e77\profile.example.ps1'
```

Comment: I found the correct `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` here: `C:\Users\[YourUserName]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`

Comment: In my case, I added the git path to System PATH environment variable so I would also have the git commands available from the Command console.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do a [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/poshgit) upgrade or reinstall of Posh Git.
`choco install poshgit`
or
    `choco upgrade poshgit`